# How to retrieve categories using a DQL query from a symfony2 blog?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have created an application in symfony2. So far, I have an entity **Users** that authenticates users, an entity **Guests** and a **Category** one.

**Users** have an OneToMany Relationship with **Guests** that keeps the guests (for an event), mapping the users.id to guests.user_id variable.

**Users** also have OneToMany Relationship with **Categories** for the same reason.

**Guests** has a ManyToMany relationship with **Categories**, as there are many guests in many categories and many categories for many guests.

I have created everything and the CRUD actions work successfully showing me all guests that a user added. I want to add the categories that every guest belongs to the View action.

I am confused. I have made a custom query to retrieve all guests for the logged in user:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
       $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
       $userId = $user->getId();

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
       $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT g
                                  FROM Acme\SomethingBundle\Entity\Guest g
                                  INNER JOIN g.user u
                                  WHERE u.id = :userId
                                  ORDER BY g.surname ASC");
        $query->setParameter('userId', $userId); 
        $entities = $query->getResult();

        return $this->render('AcmeSomethingBundle:Guest:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities
        ));
    }
```

If I try to add the **Category** Entity to the query, I am getting exceptions:

```
public function indexAction()
        {
           $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
           $userId = $user->getId();

           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
           $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT g , c
                                      FROM Acme\SomethingBundle\Entity\Guest g,
                                           Acme\SomethingBundle\Entity\Category c
                                      INNER JOIN g.user u
                                      WHERE u.id = :userId
                                      ORDER BY g.surname ASC");
            $query->setParameter('userId', $userId); 
            $entities = $query->getResult();

            return $this->render('AcmeSomethingBundle:Guest:index.html.twig', array(
                'entities' => $entities
            ));
        }
```

Please help. I am have been trying to make it work it for 6 hours now (in a series :) ).

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'g0_.user_id' in 'on clause'
500 Internal Server Error - PDOException

Comment: Try to run "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force"

Comment: Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

Comment: I believe that my query is actually wrong. Do I need an extra left join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT g
FROM Acme\MarriBundle\Entity\Guest g
LEFT JOIN g.user u
WHERE u.id = :userId
ORDER BY g.surname ASC
```

the query is right, the wrong is the twig coding. I had to create a loop because the categories were an array

```
{% for category in entity.categories %}
{{ category.name }}
{% endfor %}
```